# Odoo 13 : How to resolve two odoo themes in conflict?

Tags: odoo

I'm working on creating two themes for two odoo websites.
Let call the initial theme (that I got from a friend) theme_website_one, I duplicated it and changed the theme name to theme_website_two.
theme_website_one contains those codes :

```
$o-theme-color-palettes: (
(
    'alpha': #eb2849,
    'beta': #000000,
    'gamma': #22b8f0,
    'delta':#5b899e,
    'epsilon': #e46f78,
),
);
```

And theme_website_two contains those codes :

```
$o-theme-color-palettes: (
    (
            'alpha': #192E3F,
            'beta': #000000,
            'gamma': #FFA604,
            'delta':#E5E5E5,
            'epsilon': #000000,
    ),
);
```

Each themes have importation like this:

```
<template id="_assets_primary_variables"
          inherit_id="website._assets_primary_variables" priority="1">
    <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss"
              href="/"**theme_name**"/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

The problem is when I installed theme_website_two, It overwrites the theme_website_one and can't use theme_website_one anymore (I mean, its o-theme-color-palettes is overwited). Even if, I linked website_one to theme_webstie_one and website_two to theme_website_two.
I need that both themes work like this [one](https://www.odoo.com/apps/themes/13.0/theme_bistro/).
The manifest for theme_website_one : [**manifest**](https://pastebin.com/c9Z8xV1F)
The manifest for theme_website_two : [**manifest**](https://pastebin.com/9v9WyZMb)
Can you help me?

Comment: Include your `__manifest__.py` to question. The key may be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you guys. It is my fault, iny my branch the name of the theme modules is customer_website_one and customer_website_two but not theme_*. I renamed them all and it works as expected.